# setInterval repeats same value

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want to check the queue value every 2 seconds and if the queue value is not equal to the myData value, it will be pushing the queue value to myData.
But always setInterval push the same data to myData even if I change the queue value.
Output is always like this:
1422
1422
1422
1422

```
const queue = 1422;
let myData = [];


const queueCheck = setInterval(myCallback, 2000);

function myCallback(){
    if( queue !== myData){
        let myData = queue;
        console.log(myData);
    }
};
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but seeing your code, there are some obvious flaws visible, firstly, within the `if` block, your are comparing a variable with an array directly, secondly you're assigning the queue variable to myData array not pushing into it

Comment: What's this `queue !== myData` is supposed to mean if `queue` is a number and `myData` is an array?

Comment: `let myData` creates a new variable; if you wanted to use the global `myData` you should drop the `let` inside the function

Comment: 1) `queue` is defined as const, so u cant' change it 2) `let myData = queue` you define a new variable called `myData` inside the `myCallback` function, so u don't override the global defined `myData`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```js
const queue = {current: 1422};
let myData = [];


const queueCheck = setInterval(myCallback, 2000);

function myCallback(){
    if(!myData.includes(queue.current)){
        myData.push(queue.current)
        console.log(myData);
    }
};

queue.current = 1234;
```